# Store code being automatically added

Tags: magento2, multistore

A store is setup with multiple websites, with a single store and store view within each website.

magento-vars.php was updated with `MAGE_RUN_CODE` matching the store code. Base URLs are set.

Correct store loads for each configuration.

Problem: even though base URL for each store ends in `.com/`, a redirect is occurring from `.com/` to `.com/store_code_here`. How can I prevent it from doing this redirect, and to avoid the store code being part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable store codes via admin at below path :

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > No
```